# td height in firefox is different

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, firefox

so i have done some searching and found this issue is known but none of the fixes seem to work.

The issue is that the td height is being stretched out like this images demonstrates
https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5UYw.jpg

I have tried the following

A. setting the td height to 1px and allowing the content to stretch it.

B.adding a style and setting the height to 1 px

C. adding a div tag on the content within the td and setting the div tag height and overflow hidden

D. styling the td to have an overflow hidden

E.styling the td with display: block

I think the problem may be the iframe which is set to auto resize depending on the content within the iframe.

none of which seemed to help the page is here http://soldbybillcox.com/listings.html

I'm aware that sites should be made with divs and using tables is outdated!

Any insight into this issue is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not real fix but I ended up just using `<br/>` and pasting all the images in the top row and valign to top. It looks good but still dont know what was going on.

Comment: I think that's a good fix to get the desired result. I think if you were wanting the "real" fix, the only reasonable way would be using divs. You could get your whole page done with probably about 1/3 the code you are using.

Answer (score 1):

If you **add this** to each of the tds you want to be kept up top it will help.

```
<td colspan="2" rowspan="5" style="vertical-align:top;">
```

Ultimately it will make your life so much easier to go with divs though. It's so much cleaner!

Also you are a real estate agent so it's important to make your website validate(for SEO reasons) so I recommend that you add alt tags to all of your images(5). This will also help your Search Engine results all by itself [See Here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_alt.asp).

Comment: this moved one image up the td still remain stretched

Answer (score 0):

You could add the following rule to your CSS (which will affect all table cells)

```
#Table_01 td {
    vertical-align: top
}
```

Or add

```
style="vertical-align: top"
```

as an attribute to this one table cell only

Comment: I will try in a few hours and post back! Thanks!